# How to change a variable from within a method of another class Java

Tags: java

While working on a project, I ran into a problem I have not ran into before (I am quite new at Java).

Basically this is the problem:

I have two classes in my project, `ClassA` and `ClassB`. Inside of my `main` I create an instance of both classes. The problem comes when I want to write a method for `ClassB` that does something with the *instance* of `ClassA` that I created. I don't know if this is possible at all, or how to get around it.

ClassA:

```java
class ClassA {
   ///...
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ClassA a = new ClassA();
      ClassB b = new ClassB();
   }
}
```

ClassB:

```java
class ClassB() {
   ///...
   public void doSomething(){
      //do something with the instance of classA
   }
}
```

Comment: Add a parameter to method `doSomething` (in class `B`), i.e. `public void doSomething(ClassA a)` Then in method `main` add this line: `b.doSomething(a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities you can use, depending on your concrete problem and architecture:

**Instance passing on construction**

When creating an instance of `ClassB`, you can hand over the `ClassA` instance, like this:

```java
class ClassB() {

   private ClassA classA;

   public ClassB(ClassA classA) {
     this.classA = classA;
   }
   ///...
   public void doSomething() {
      classA.doSomething();
      //do something with the instance of classA
   }
}
```

Your `main` method should then look like this:

```java
class ClassA {
   ///...
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ClassA a = new ClassA();
      ClassB b = new ClassB(a); //<-- Here the constructor passing takes place
   }
}
```

Doing it this way, `ClassB` will allow for a `ClassA` instance to be given when being constructed. (If you don't want this to happen every time, you could add an additional constructor without parameters.)

**Instance passing via setter**

Very similarly, you can also add a setter to ClassB:

```java
class ClassB() {

   private ClassA classA;

   public void setClassA(ClassA classA) {
     this.classA = classA; //<-- here the local instance variable is populated
   }

   ///...
   public void doSomething() {
      classA.doSomething();
      //do something with the instance of classA
   }
}
```

Your `main` method should then look like this:

```java
class ClassA {
   ///...
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ClassA a = new ClassA();
      ClassB b = new ClassB();
      b.setClassA(a);
   }
}
```

In this case, you need to make sure, that `setClassA` is called before your `ClassB` instance tries to `doSomething` with the `ClassA` instance. (Anyway, you should always check whether `classA` is `null` before trying to operate on it.)

**Instance passing on function call**

(Update: I forgot this one when posting my original answer. Abras comment is very helpful too!)

You can change your `doSomething()` method to accept a `ClassA` instance as parameter:

```java
class ClassB() {
   ///...
   public void doSomething(Class a){
      a.doSomething(); // <-- use the passed-in ClassA instance
      //do something with the instance of classA
   }
}
```

You would then have to adapt your call to `doSomething` of the `ClassB` instance and supply a `ClassA` instance.

**Subclassing**

If you make `ClassB` a subclass of `ClassA`, they can "share" their variables. It would then look like this:

```java
class ClassA {

   private ClassA a;
   ///...
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ClassA a = new ClassA();
      ClassB b = new ClassB();
   }

   class ClassB {
     public void doSomething() {
       a.doSomething(); //<-- here, the "a" variable of the "outer" class is used
       //do something with the instance of classA
     }
   }
}
```

In this case, there's no need to explicitly hand over the `ClassA` instance to `ClassB`. Anyway, you should use subclasses only in limited contexts, e. g. if it is not used anywhere else in your application.

**Other possibilities**

Other possibilities include more advanced design patterns like Singletons, Services, and so on. This would probably go beyond the scope of this answer.

**One last remark**

In your example, `ClassA` is containing the `main` method and also creating an instance of itself and dealing with it. Nevertheless this is possible, it seems a to be code smell to me. You could think about migrating your `main` method to a separate class.

Comment: Thank you an awful lot! After wrecking my brains over this for very long, your suggestion has given me the solution! The subclassing method at the end helped me get there. And regarding your last remark: I already had that but for simplicity reasons I didn't write it like that in my example. Again thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this

```
public class B() {
  public void doSomething(ClassA classA) {
     classA.someNonStaticMethodFromClassA()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you intend to do with the instance of `ClassA`?

Say you want to modify a `ClassA` public variable from `ClassB`, here's an example

ClassA:

```
class ClassA {

  public int someVariable = 10;

  ///...
  public static void main(String[] args){
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    b.doSomething(a);
  }
}
```

ClassB:

```
class ClassB {
  ///...
  public void doSomething(ClassA a){
    a.someVariable = 5;
  }
}
```

That's the most basic way of doing it, but an OOP programmer would almost never do it like that.

Here's another example: Say that, for some reason, you want `someVariable` to be modified only when the new value is greater than 12

ClassA:

```
class ClassA {

  private int someVariable = 10;

  public void setSomeVariable(int newValue) {
    if(newValue > 12) {
      someVariable = newValue;
    }
  }

   ///...
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ClassA a = new ClassA();
      ClassB b = new ClassB();
      b.doSomething(a);
   }
}
```

ClassB:

```
class ClassB {
   ///...
   public void doSomething(ClassA a){
       a.setSomeVariable(15);
   }
}
```

In this example, the `setSomeVariable` method is called a **setter**, because it sets a **private** variable that would otherwise be inaccessible from `ClassB`.

Usually you use setters when you want to perform checks on the new value (like we did) or when you want to do some operations once the variable is set. There are also **getter**s methods, see for yourself when to use them.

p.s. : if you don't know what `public` and `private` stand for, or when and why to use them, I suggest you google that as well.